# Need to convert NSArray from fetchRequest to an object before saving to core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a to-many relationship between two entities: "Books" and "Library" in Core Data.

In my EditBooks controller, I have a pickerview populated with a few libraries. I need to take the selected library from that picker and pass it as relationship property in my Books Managed Object Subclass.

My books have an inverse relationship with Library, bookToLibrary <----> libraryToBook.

I need to populate the Books.bookToLibrary relationship for a book being added or edited with the value from the picker view. My fetchRequest object of user's selection of the pickerview works and is an NSArray.

How do I convert that to an Object of my Library subclass so that I can use the ManageObjectContext to connect the relationship?

```
 var rowPick = supPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
 var choice = libraryArray[rowPick]

 var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Library")
 request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "libraryName = %@",choice)
 request.predicate = predicate
 var libresults = self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request,      error: nil)!
  //libresults is a NSArray of the object I want. It works fine. I need to get that object into the bookToLibrary relationship

  // book?.bookToLibrary  = results <---results needs to be a Library object
  managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
```

Comment: i Think you have one to one relationship with library. It should be one to many relationship beween library to book.

Comment: Use `book?.bookToLibrary  = libresults[0]`, though you should add some error checking to ensure there is only one Library matching your request.

Comment: It is a many to one relationship.  bookToLibrary.